# Issue 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' in a Swagger openAPI Annotations

Tags: php, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I use these packages (installed via composer)

> "swagger-api/swagger-ui": "^3.0",
>   "zircote/swagger-php": "~2.0|3.*"

In my def controller I have these annotations

```
/**
 * @OA\Info(title="My API", version="0.1")
 * @OA\Schemes(format="http")
 * @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityScheme="bearerAuth",
 *      in="header",
 *      name="Authorization",
 *      type="http",
 *      scheme="Bearer",
 *      bearerFormat="JWT",
 * ),
 * @OA\Tag(
 *     name="Auth",
 *     description="Auth endpoints",
 * )
 * @OA\Tag(
 *     name="Users",
 *     description="Users endpoints",
 * )
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
```

Then I have method

```
/**
 * 
 * @OA\Get(
 *      path="/users",
 *      operationId="getListOfUsers",
 *      tags={"Users"},
 *      description="Get list of users",
 *      security={{"bearerAuth":{}}}, 
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="Authorization",
 *         in="header",
 *         required=true,
 *         description="Bearer {access-token}",
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *              type="bearerAuth"
 *         ) 
 *      ), 
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="Get list of users.",
 *          @OA\JsonContent(type="object",
 *              @OA\Property(property="message", type="string"),
 *              @OA\Property(property="data", type="array",
 *                  @OA\Items(type="object",
 *                      @OA\Property(property="id", type="integer"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="name", type="string"),
 *                      @OA\Property(property="email", type="string"),
 *                  ),
 *              ),
 *          ),
 *       ),
 *       @OA\Response(response=401, description="Unauthorized"),
 *       @OA\Response(response=404, description="Not Found"),
 * )
 * 
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function users()
```

So, when I try to test this route via swagger ui, I am getting error

> 401, "message": "Unauthenticated."

When I checked header (Firefox), I have not seen

> Authorization: Bearer {{access-token}}

but I have my token in

> Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik5COUV5Y1ltRTM4eXNsRlpLY2ptTGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiNDFCbG95c1RHSHRFT0IyWWZ4aWFRQVJ6RHhTS1A4SFJiQXp2amlQc3RCUFRUWWs5R3RQQ0ZlakdFNnlvRm50MSIsIm1hYyI6ImM...

Swagger UI does not send header properly. What is wrong in annotations? Thanks

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 17):

Authorization has nothing to do with XSRF-TOKEN. 
I also had the same issue and solved it after several hours of googling. Here are the changes you might want to try:

Remove these lines:

```
 *      @OA\Parameter(
 *         name="Authorization",
 *         in="header",
 *         required=true,
 *         description="Bearer {access-token}",
 *         @OA\Schema(
 *              type="bearerAuth"
 *         ) 
 *      ),
```

And change this:

```
 * @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *      securityScheme="bearerAuth",
 *      in="header",
 *      name="Authorization",
 *      type="http",
 *      scheme="Bearer",
 *      bearerFormat="JWT",
 * ),
```

to

```
* @OA\SecurityScheme(
*      securityScheme="bearerAuth",
*      in="header",
*      name="bearerAuth",
*      type="http",
*      scheme="bearer",
*      bearerFormat="JWT",
* ),
```

Note that the "Bearer" and "bearer" are differed.

Comment: how do u pass the token here ??

Comment: You can pass the token via the UI.

Comment: can we some how set a default token ?